# Privileged Helper tool Installation Issue osx 10.10.1

Tags: macos, elevated-privileges, osx-yosemite

I have developed a helper tool which works fine till OS X 10.10, but I didn't able to install it on 10.10.1. It gives an error that your tool is not installed successfully or authorization failed error occurs. I am trying to install helper tool using Install tool using authorizationexecutewithprivileges an old approach but it did work for me till 10.10. Does anyone have idea about updates in new version of OS X which causes this issue?

Comment: Please share error code

Answer (score 2):

Well since you did not specify any other information, apart from your description, that might help anyone answer the question, I think, "based off of your explanation", you should

- Check for any log messages in the Console App. I have myself come across this where the SMJobBless api failed with internal error and looking at the system log message helped.
- Manually remove your helper app from the /Library/PrivilegedHelperTool Folder and retry the installation.